# Need to access embedded youtube videos current time

Tags: javascript, iframe, time, youtube

I'm making a site with embedded youtube videos, 
The videos need to pause on several occasions during the playback, and it need to be on specific times.

I've checked out the api, and it has taken me a bit down the road, but I'm not able to get it working.

This: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Getting_Started
does half of the job, but I can't seem to work around it to do what I want though.

Any suggestions to what I can use so that something like this would work?

```
 player.getCurrentTime();
 if(player.getCurrentTime == time[i]){
    player.pauseVideo();
 }
```

Or.. if there's a more efficient method, I'm all ears. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution my problem.

```
 var count;
  var time;
  var vid1 = [10,20,30,40];
  function timerCount() {
      count = Math.round(player.getCurrentTime());
      document.getElementById("time").value = count;
      time = setTimeout("timerCount()", 1000);
      for(var i = 0; i< vid1.length; i++){
        if(count == vid1[i]){
          pauseVideo();
        }
      }
  }
  function pauseVideo() {
         player.pauseVideo();
         player.seekTo(count +1);
  }
```